# How to replace Moen Finley faucet aerator

Tags: water, faucet, kitchen-sink, stuck, water-filtration

[image]

after dripping water from my kitchen faucet during freezing temp, my aerator blew out of it. I can’t find any info how to replace. Moen cust service did not call at my scheduled time slot and they are not taking calls normally- only by appointment. I tried pulling the inner rubber piece that’s left off with needle nose pliers. There are no circular grooves behind that for me to screw in an aerator I got from Lowe’s. So I’m wondering if I have to unscrew the last segment of the faucet and replace from the other end? However I can’t get that piece loose after using WD-40. I haven’t tried channel locks or anything bc I’m not even sure that piece is supposed to come off. And I’m not sure I’m turning the right way… facing the faucet, do I turn to the left for it to be counter clockwise? Pls help. Could not find a similar faucet on YouTube or anywhere else. It’s a Moen Finley model number 87313SRS.

[image]

I can’t get the end piece off! I’ve tried WD 40 and submerging and holding in white vinegar. It hasn’t budged. It probably hasn’t come off in 10 years. I saw a guy on YouTube use CLR in a balloon on the end of the faucet to keep submerged. It was for a different type of faucet though. Would you recommend that? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Think the end piece unscrews.  After it is off should be able to just the aerator out.  They are usually small pieces so blocking the drain is a good idea.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know what kind of aerator I should use to replace it? I found the faucet manual online but it just says “aerator kit” and the model number. Can I use one from Lowe’s or Amazon? Female or male? Just measure the faucet opening for size?

Comment: Would match with the model number or just take it to local plumbing place(big box, plumbing store)

Comment: Soaking the end of the spout in CLR to clean it is brand/model agnostic. _If_ the problem is corrosion/mineral build up, that will work on your faucet just as well as it did in the video you watched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end piece unscrews.

Using vinegar to loosen the build up.

Put some vinegar in a glass and dip the end in to it, let it work.

Usually they are just screwed in with fingers, thus no tools neded.

Cover the drain to prevent parts falling in.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try vinegar. It’s on there pretty tight.  If I’m looking at the faucet, do I turn it to the left? Someone said bc it’s upside down, the direction is different than you would expect?

Comment: it would unscrew turning left, if you must use tools, be gentle not to scratch, make sure you block the drain to prevent parts falling in

Comment: You might want to consider getting a strap wrench, which lets you wrap a thick rubber strap around the piece and use a lever to turn it: it's designed so leverage from the handle also tightens the strap to strengthen the grip. Since it doesn't need metal to metal contact, it's unlikely to damage the finish. Also be careful about the turning direction: counterclockwise as viewed looking up into the pipe, clockwise when seen from above. That's all assuming that the aerator piece does indeed unscrew, of course; I haven't disassembled one of these.

Comment: Also, if the problem is mineral buildup, giving it a few taps with a hammer handle (note, I said handle!) might be enough to fracture a few crystals and loosen it's grip.